# How to handle exceptions correctly?

Tags: python, variables, exception

I don't quite understand yet how to correctly use exceptions in Python. I want to process the data I can't completely trust (they are prone to change, and if they change, script may break). Let's say I process a webpage using BeautifulSoup. If author of the website make some changes to his website, some statements may rise exception. Let's look at this code example:

```
data = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/somedocument.php').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, convertEntities="html")

name = soup.find('td', text=re.compile(r'^Name$')).parent.nextSibling.string

print name
```

Now, if `soup.find()` fail because owner of that website will change content of the website and rename cell `Name` to `Names`, an exception `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'` will be raised. But I don't mind! I expect that some data won't be available. I just want to proceed and use what variables I have available (of course there will be some data I NEED, and if they are unavailable I will simply exit.

Only solution I came up with is:

```
try: name = soup.find('td', text=re.compile(r'^Name$')).parent.nextSibling.string
except AttributeError: name = False
try: email = soup.find('td', text=re.compile(r'^Email$')).parent.nextSibling.string
except AttributeError: email = False
try: phone = soup.find('td', text=re.compile(r'^Phone$')).parent.nextSibling.string
except AttributeError: phone = False

if name: print name
if email: print email
if phone: print phone
```

Is there any better way, or should I just continue making try-except for every similar statement? It doesn't look very nice at all.

EDIT: Best solution for me would be like this:

```
try:
    print 'do some stuff here that may throw and exception'
    print non_existant_variable_that_throws_an_exception_here
    print 'and few more things to complete'
except:
    pass
```

This would be great, but `pass` will skip anything in `try` code block, so `and few more things to complete` will never be printed. If there was something like pass, but it would just ignore the error and continue executing, it would be great.

Comment: Use `finally`. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Comment: "pass will skip anything in try code block".  Correct.  Why put so many statements in the `try:` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if you don't mind the exception you can just let it pass:

```
try:
    something()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

but never do *this* as it is will let *all* errors pass:

```
try:
    something()
except Exception:
    pass
```

As for your code sample, perhaps it could be tidied up with something like this:

```
myDict = {}

for item in ["Name", "Email", "Phone"]:
    try:
        myDict[item] = soup.find('td', text=re.compile(r'^%s$' % item)).parent.nextSibling.string
    except Attribute
        myDict[item] = "Not found"

for item in ["Name", "Email", "Phone"]:
    print "%s: %s" % (item, myDict[item])
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion first suggestion. If I am not mistaken it should be `except` instead of `catch`. But anyway, look at my edited question. As for the second suggestion I understand my example would make sense to use dict and do something like what you suggested. But it was just example, I don't think it would work very well in my case. I'd prefer just checking if variable is available and use it, if not, then continue.

Comment: Oh yeah, whoops I was in a hurry I guess. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a try/finally statement instead?

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Example from the docs:

```
>>> def divide(x, y):
...     try:
...         result = x / y
...     except ZeroDivisionError:
...         print "division by zero!"
...     else:
...         print "result is", result
...     finally:
...         print "executing finally clause"
```

So, to use your example:

```
try:
    do_some_stuff_here_that_may_throw_an_exception()
except someError:
    print "That didn't work!"
else:
    print variable_that_we_know_didnt_throw_an_exception_here
finally:
    print "finishing up stuff"
```

"finally" will always excecute, so that's where you can put your "finishing up" stuff.